# Make Mockito 1.x throw an exception the first N calls, then return a value?

Tags: java, mockito

From the Mockito 1.x documentation, I see this example, which is almost exactly what I need:

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
  .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
  .thenReturn("foo");
```

What I really need is something like this:

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
  .thenThrow(new RuntimeException(), times(2))
  .thenReturn("foo");
```

I could simply duplicate the "thenThrow()" call, but that seems hacky.  It would be nice if I could just say do this step N times, and then do the next thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to invoke `thenThrow()` 2 times, I don't think that this duplication be a serious issue :

```
.when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
.thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
.thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
.thenReturn("foo");
```

Now if you need to invoke `thenThrow()` more than 2 times, creating a utility class to enrich Mockito feature is probably the best thing to do.
You could also submit a request to the mockito team to add this feature.

You could for example create a method that creates an array of `Throwable` :

```
private static Throwable[] chainedThrow(Supplier<Throwable> supplier, int times) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, times)
                    .mapToObj(i -> supplier.get())
                    .toArray(Throwable[]::new);
}
```

And invoke it in this way for example to throw 2 times the exception :

```
Mockito.when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
  .thenThrow(chainedThrow(RuntimeException::new, 2))
  .thenReturn("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

thenTrow method can take a var-args. It means you can do the following:

```
when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
  .thenThrow(new RuntimeException(), new RuntimeException())
  .thenReturn("foo");
```

So you don't need to duplicate the thenThrow() method call. But sure, this solution may not be great if you want to throw an exception something like 10 times...

Maybe if Ineed to throw an exception 10 times with Mockito, I would write something like:

```
Exception[] exceptions = new Exception[10];
for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.length ; i++) {
   exceptions[i] = new RuntimeException();
}
when(mock.someMethod()).thenThrow(exceptions);
```